# Mining your transaction to push it to the blockchain?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, block

Is there a way to mine your own transaction to push it to the block chain.

I see these individual miners out there on forums speeding up other users transactions within 10-60 minutes.

So i guess i am trying to figure out how i can do this to speed up my 3 stuck transactions!

Any info would be nice! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can pay to mining pools to mine your stuck transactions.

Expensive but i don't know any other mining pools who provides this feature.

https://pushtx.btc.com/

Try to push your stuck transactions before you pay, maybe that could help you if your transactions have more than 120/sat per byte.

> https://insight.bitpay.com/tx/send
>
> https://blockchain.info/pushtx
>
> https://blockexplorer.com/tx/send
>
> https://btc.com/tools/tx/publish
>
> https://coinb.in/#broadcast
>
> https://chain.localbitcoins.com/tx/send
>
> http://webbtc.com/relay_tx
>
> https://www.smartbit.com.au/txs/pushtx
>
> https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/pushtx/
>
> https://www.f2pool.com/pushtx (Needs referral code from pool operator.)
>
> https://pool.viabtc.com/tools/BTC/broadcast/
>
> https://chainquery.com/bitcoin-api/sendrawtransaction

Some websites asks for hex format transaction ID, You could convert it like that:

https://blockchain.info/tx/**TransactionID Here**?format=hex

Comment: Not what i am asking. I tried all of that.